# How to display concatenated sql column values using foreach loop in Razor view

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a table like this :

```
id    | movie        | celeb    | role 
------+--------------+----------+---------
79    | Terminator   | Arnold   | Actor 
174   | Avengers     | Robert   | Actor
174   | Avengers     | Scarlett | Actress
```

By using

```
STRING_AGG(CONCAT(celeb, ' ', role), ', ') AS CelebRole
```

in a SQL Server procedure, I get the following output :

```
id   | movie        | CelebRole 
-----+--------------+----------------------
79   | Terminator   | Arnold Actor 
174  | Avengers     | Robert Actor, Scarlett Actress
```

Now in my razor view, using foreach loop, i do this :

```
  @{ var cr = @item.CelebRole.Split(','); }

  @foreach(var c in cr)
  {
    <li>@c</li>
  }
```

This displays the record in the view like this:

```
1. Robert Actor
2. Scarlett Actress
```

How can I split the **'Robert' and 'Actor'** such that I get :

```
   <sometag>Robert</sometag><br>
   <sometag>Actor</sometag>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to split not just by `,` sign, but with `space` character:

```
@{ var cr = @item.CelebRole.Split(new char[] { ',', ' ' }
    , StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); }

@foreach(var c in cr)
{
    <li>@c</li>
}
```

Comment: Okk I'll try this and let you know ...

Comment: Hello @StepUp .. This gives the result one after another in a <li>, its good it has split it, but if Celeb Role contains **two words** like say... **'Action Director'** in this case.. the Action & Director get again get split.. so how can i handle two words ?